# How are the random numbers in SSL obfuscated to prevent a third party from generating the same master key?

Tags: ssl, network-security

My understanding of how SSL works:

The client sends a hello message containing the SSL version number, supported key, cipher and hash methods, and a randomly generated number.

Server replies selecting the key, cipher and hash methods, a randomly generated number, and its certificate.

Client and server generate a master key based on above randomly generated number(s).

Client request change cipher, server replies change cipher, and they are now both encrypted with the master key.

My question is that wouldn't a third party (eg man in the middle) be able to intercept the initial hello messages, use the intercepted randomly generated numbers and figure out the master key, and thereby able to figure out what the rest of the messages are for the entirety of the connection? Thanks!

Comment: Several false statements here. That 'random' number is the public key that is linked to a private key. But yes, without a certificate (signed by a trusted third party) this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle.

Comment: SSL/TLS key derivation uses the two 'random' values, which are not secret, and the 'premaster secret' which _is_ secret and varies depending on the key exchange used of which there are several possibilities and you gave no clue which you are using. Also the master secret isn't used directly to encrypt, but rather to derive _multiple_ working keys. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/ or more specifically https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63971/how-is-the-premaster-secret-used-in-tls-generated ...

Comment: ... or the RFCs, which vary (slightly) by version -- do you mean _actual_ SSL (Secure Sockets Layer by Netscape) which is now broken and obsolete and not used, or TLS (Transport Layer Security by IETF) which is the improved/fixed version implemented by nearly all the same software, much of which still uses the obsolete _name_ SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SSL can encrypt your message and traffic.
2. If `man in the middle` able to intercept, he'll see an encrypted message but not danger because that's hash function a way.

Good luck!

By @Jackie